# Does Windows Server 2012 support Raw Sockets?

Tags: winsock, raw-sockets

Trying to find out if Windows Server 2012 has the same limitation on Raw Sockets as Windows 7. The MSDN documentation is unclear on this.

Comment: Which limitation are you referring to exactly?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740548(v=vs.85).aspx


On Windows 7, Windows Vista, Windows XP with Service Pack 2 (SP2), and Windows XP with Service Pack 3 (SP3), the ability to send traffic over raw sockets has been restricted in several ways...

Comment: Yes, that limitation exists on all modern OS versions.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is just because it hasn't been updated.